# Find the sum of user input (only the positive integers) C#

Tags: c#

Find the sum of user input (only the positive integers). The code I wrote calculates them in weird way and i got confused. Thanks in advance.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers lenght: ");
        int lenght = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int sum = 0;
        int input = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < lenght; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

           if(input >= 0)
            {
                sum = input + input;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the positive numbers is: " + sum);
```

Comment: try `sum += input`

Comment: `sum = input + input` is wrong. Should be `sum = sum + input` which can be shortened to `sum += input`

Comment: Works ! Thanks man

Comment: The name of the variable `lenght` is spelled incorrectly, it should have been named `length`. (Does SO have an off-topic tag? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sum = input + input;** is wrong,

change it to :

```
sum = sum + input;
```

or

```
sum += input;
```